# How to use Standalone Aspire dashboard in Blazor 8?

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0, dotnet-aspire

In this video: [https://youtu.be/BnjHArsYGLM?si=hzogiatb4-*323S*&t=463](https://youtu.be/BnjHArsYGLM?si=hzogiatb4-_323S_&t=463)
@SamSpencer and @NoaFolk talk about OpenTelemetry and .NET8.

Around 7:43 Noa talks about the standalone Aspire dashboard and how you can use it without the need for a full Aspire projects setup.

Sadly they didn't share a working repo.

I've created a new Blazor WebApp using the new template for .NET 8 (the template creates two projects, a ServerSide and ClientSide one) and I added OpenTelemetry. I use the ConsoleExporter and I can see it is logging like I want. I even added a few metrics.

But I can't get the Dashboard to work. Does anybody else get this working?

This is my Program.cs, in my ServerSide project:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CustomMeters>();

builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .WithMetrics(metrics => metrics
            .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting")
            .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel")
            .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections")
            .AddMeter("System.NET.Http")
            .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
            .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
            .AddOtlpExporter())              // <== This should create the dashboard
    .WithTracing(tracing => tracing
            .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())
            .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
            .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
    );

// Clear default logging providers used by WebApplication host.
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();

builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry(options =>
{
    options.AddConsoleExporter();
    options.AddOtlpExporter(otlpOptions =>
        otlpOptions.Endpoint = new Uri(builder.Configuration.GetValue("Otlp:Endpoint", defaultValue: "http://localhost:4317")!));
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

var app = builder.Build();
[..]
```

Comment: That video doesn't talk about the .NET Aspire Dashboard. It shows how you can add OTEL to a project and show traces/metrics in a *Grafana* dashboard. At 7:43 they're talking about whether you need the OTLP Exporter or not, since they already export to Prometheus. In .NET Aspire, the Aspire host builder also hosts *Aspire's* dashboard.

Comment: That said, having Aspire Dashboard as a standalone makes great sense and there's a [Github issue for this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspire/issues/847).

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos Then I completely misunderstood the video. I do understand they're using Prometheus and Grafana but I understood at 9:11 they show the standalone Aspire dashboard. And then at 10:30 they show the Grafana dashboard.

Comment: Dashboard is standalone in the latest Aspire preview and can ingest OTEL data from any source, not just those registered with Aspire. I use it as a "desktop OTEL viewer" even for Python projects

Comment: Refer this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/aspire-samples/aspire-standalone-dashboard/
Its working